# Internet Explorer 11 Overlay does not close

Tags: modal-dialogs

I am experiencing an issue where the overlay wont close when saving a piece of content. This only happens on Internet Explorer 11. I've tested it on Chrome Firefox and IE 10 and it is working fine.

The problem is when I save content, the overlay modal disappears and I'm left with a grayed out page and cant click or do anything. Also when I save a setting everything saves but I cant exit the modal and if I click another admin link the site forces itself to non-overlay mode. Weird stuff! Anyone ever experience this problem? Again its only on Internet Explorer 11.

I thought it might be jQuery related so I checked every version of jQuery that I use with the jQuery update module and it didn't fix it.

Comment: Does this happen when the jquery update module is disabled?

Comment: Good idea. When I disable jquery update all admin pages force non-overlay, this only happens for IE 11. Chrome and Firfox both still display content in overlay when jquery update is off. Weird because I have a custom dashboard that will display in overlay. So I know it works.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it yay! It was a problem with jquery update. I updated the module to the alpha3 release which adds support for jquery version 1.11 and it works fine now.